# Wordpress meta_query taxonomy don't work

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

On my blogI tried sucessfully to make a research for articles titles and content, but after I tried to make a research for custom taxonomy of articles 'categories' with `meta_query()` and `REGEXP`, didn't work.

My form :

```
<div class="zone_filters">
  <form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="249" />
    <input type="text" name="search_input" />
    <select name="type">
        <option value="title">titre et texte</option>
        <option value="category">catégorie</option>
    </select>
    <select name="orderby">
        <option value="DESC">plus récent</option>
        <option value="ASC">plus ancien</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

My arguments :

```
<?php 

$orderby = 'DESC';

if($_GET['orderby']) {

    $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'orderby' => array('date' => $orderby)
);

if($_GET['type'] == 'title') {

    $args['s'] = $_GET['search_input'];
}
elseif($_GET['type'] == 'category') {

    $value = '^[a-zA-Z|\s]*(' . strtoupper( $_GET['search_input']) . '|' . strtolower( $_GET['search_input']) . ')[a-zA-Z|\s]*$';

    $args['meta_query'] = array(array('key' => 'categories', 'value' => $value, 'compare' => 'REGEXP'));

}

$query = new WP_Query($args);?>
```

I learned it from [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
and I can't found the differences between my code and the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tax query for category.

```
$args['tax_query'] = array(array('taxonomy' => 'categories', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $value));
```

**as per your html**

```
<div class="zone_filters">
  <form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="249" />
    <input type="text" name="search_input" />
    <select name="type">
        <option value="">titre et texte</option>
        <option value="category-1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="category-2">Category 2</option>
        <option value="category-3">Category 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="orderby">
        <option value="DESC">plus récent</option>
        <option value="ASC">plus ancien</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
  </form>
</div>

<?php 

$orderby = 'DESC';

if($_GET['orderby']) {

    $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'orderby' => array('date' => $orderby)
);

if($_GET['type'] == 'title') {

    $args['s'] = $_GET['search_input'];
}
elseif($_GET['type'] == 'category') {

    $value = '^[a-zA-Z|\s]*(' . strtoupper( $_GET['search_input']) . '|' . strtolower( $_GET['search_input']) . ')[a-zA-Z|\s]*$';

    $args['tax_query'] = array(array('taxonomy' => 'categories', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $value));

}

$query = new WP_Query($args);?>
```

Comment: are you searching with category name for "categories" taxonomy right?

Comment: <option value="category slug here">category name here</option> as per the your taxonomy

Comment: It's a good way to do it. And easiest than the search bar. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's working this way :

Form :

```
<div class="zone_filters">
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="249" />
        <input type="text" name="search_input" />
        <select name="categories">

            <?php $allterms = get_terms('categories');

            foreach($allterms as $term) : ?>

                <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>

            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
        <select name="orderby">
            <option value="DESC">plus récent</option>
            <option value="ASC">plus ancien</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The arguments :

```
<?php 

$orderby = 'DESC';

if($_GET['orderby']) {

    $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'orderby' => array('date' => $orderby)
);

if($_GET['search_input'] != '') {

    $args['s'] = $_GET['search_input'];
}
elseif($_GET['categories']) {

    $args['categories'] = $_GET['categories'];
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);?>
```